# Dropbox - no local copy, possible?

Tags: linux, ssd, dropbox

Arch user here.

I wanted to use DropBox to free some space from my SSD. Is it possible to use DropBox in the same manner as I am currently using their web interface?

So, the question again: I don't want dropbox to store **ANYTHING** onto my SSD, I want to use DropBox as a NAS or backup drive. How to achieve that?

Comment: I don't understand the question. If the location of the Dropbox folder is on the SSD, then of course it'll store something there. Put the location on a HDD. But then again, why would you use Dropbox to free some space? Dropbox is a syncing tool—it syncs your hard drive with cloud storage. You don't free space with it.

Comment: @slhck: I want the same workflow as with web interface, just in nautilus (gnome filesystem manager). I don't want to have a LOCAL COPY.

Comment: So in essence you want the files to be displayed on your computer but without them actually being stored there?

Comment: It's sneaky marketing to trick us into thinking we have unlimited cloud space isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

If I get your question right, you want to use a file manager like nautilus to browse your Dropbox folder without actually having a Dropbox folder on your local disk.  The only way to achieve this, that comes to my mind would be a **webDAV access** to your Dropbox folder.

As far as I know there is no webDAV access provided by Dropbox, unless you use third-party tools like: https://www.dropdav.com/

Comment: gvfs support for WebDAV is mediocre at best. I also don't like the non-free (in both senses of the word) nature of Dropdav.

Answer (score 1):

From Dropbox official site:

1. Click on the Dropbox icon from the system tray.
2. Click on the gear icon and select Preferences... from the menu.
3. Click the Account tab.
4. Click the Selective Sync... button.

A window will appear with a list of all the top level folders in your Dropbox folder. The folders with a check next to them will be synced to your computer. **Uncheck any folders that you don't need to sync to your computer's hard drive**. When you're done, select OK. Any folders you deselected will be removed from your hard drive, but will still be available through the website and on any computers linked to your Dropbox account.

Comment: Yes, but then those folders are unavailable for access. See the word in bold in my question. I don't want anything stored on my SSD, not even one file.

Comment: I think dropbox client was created to store your (custom) Dropbox files locally. If you don't want to store any file on your system, the best option is to continue using web interface.

Comment: Yup, just go to http://dropbox.com , log in , and select upload files. Choose your files, upload them, then delete them from your SSD. You don't even need to install the Dropbox client on your computer.